# How to instantiate a game object using variables provided from within an array list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2d game that will create disasters around a world map in different countries. I am setting up an algorithm to randomly generate a game object representing a disaster in that country. The algorithm will be called every in game day(using a timer class). I have an array list set up containing data about each specific location a disaster can occur eg. country name and x,y co-ords.

How can I create a new game object using these specific variables?

I have created the timer class and I have also set up an array list with 5 possible locations.

```
public List<DisasterData> disaster = new List<DisasterData>();

    private void Start()
    {
        disaster.Add(new DisasterData
        {
            countryName = "England",
            x = 1.5,
            y = 5.7
        });

        disaster.Add(new DisasterData
        {
            countryName = "Albania",
            x = 10,
            y = 4
        });

        disaster.Add(new DisasterData
        {
            countryName = "Scotland",
            x = 13,
            y = 2
        });

        disaster.Add(new DisasterData
        {
            countryName = "China",
            x = 7.2,
            y = 8.3
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set values on a GameObject using these values?  Or how to spawn a specific GameObject using these values?  You said you have what type of disasters can appear in a region, so I am assuming like a Tornado could appear or maybe an earthquake, and you have a GameObject that is designated to represent that type of disaster, in that type of region, so you are trying to determine how to spawn those specific Game Objects?  Aka China can get "Earthquake" or "Tornado" depending on the season, so you want to spawn the "Tornado" Object because the values are specific to that?

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a gameObject you get the reference of that object by doing so :

`GameObject go = Instantiate(...);`

Then if there is a script attached to that object, just get it using

`YourScript script = go.GetComponent<YourScript>();`

Then you can assign values to your variables, call public functions and so on